# Javascript function "does not exist". Bad syntax but can't see it

Tags: javascript, html

The javascript is supposed to handle form submission. However, even if called with
script src="js/registerform.js"> Uncaught ReferenceError: sendreg is not defined .
The function is called onclick. Can be reproduced on www.r4ge.ro while trying to register as well as live edited. Tried jshint.com but no clue.

I will edit with any snips required.

```
    function sendreg() {
          var nameie = $("#fname").val();
          var passwordie = $("#fpass").val();
          var emailie = $("#fmail").val();
          if (nameie == '' || passwordie == '' || emailie == '') {
             alert("Please fill all the forms before submitting!");
          } else {
             // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
             $.post("http://r4ge.ro/php/register.php", {
                numeleluii: nameie,
                pass: passwordie,
                mail: emailie
             }, function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
                setTimeout(fillhome, 1000);
             });
          }
    }

    function sendpass() {
       var oldpassw = $("#oldpass").val();
       var newpassw = $("#newpass").val();
       if (oldpassw == '' || newpassw == '') {
          alert("Please fill all the forms before submitting!");
       } else {
          // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
          $.post("http://r4ge.ro/php/security.php", {
             xoldpass: oldpassw,
             xnewpass: newpassw
          }, function(data2) {
             alert(data2);
             $('#passform')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
          });
       }
    }

    function sendmail()
    {
    var curpass = $("#curpass").val();
    var newmail = $("#newmail").val();
    if (curpass == '' || newmail == '') 
    {
        alert("Please fill all the forms before submitting!");
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
        $.post("http://r4ge.ro/php/security.php", {
        curpass: curpass,
        newmail: newmail
        }, function(data3) {
        alert(data3);
        $('#mailform')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
        });
    }
    }
```

Comment: `setTimeout(fillhome(), 1000);` should be `setTimeout(fillhome, 1000);`

Comment: edited, but no cigar

Comment: When does the error ocurr?

Comment: @AronH. not sure what you are using to edit this but i have found eclipse to always be my saving grace when looking to find a missing bracket or ; (dont have that at work or i would try to find it for you

Comment: Does the error occur on page load or when the button is clicked?

Comment: This sounds very much like a scoping issue. Make sure you're 1) including the file 2) including above the button click call

Comment: @workabyte I'm using notepad++, the script was working at first and I did something and broke it. atBrennan it occurs every time you click the button, no error on load since it's not used.  atphil that was the issue. I didn't notice I was on the only other html of the page. Sorry for the dumb question. Thanks for your time. Wouldn't have noticed.

Answer (score 1):

<del>I'm guessing here but... I imagine you are doing something like
...`<button onclick="sendreg">...`</del>

<del>And you have your `<script>` in the bottom on the code. Just put them on top or use `$("#mybtn").click(sendreg)`</del>

Try using `$("#mybtn").click(sendreg)` instead of inline `onclick`.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the script comes before the button or after, the value is evaluated when the button is clicked, not when the code is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax error there, and I don't see any such error when trying the page.

The error that you get is that you can't make a cross domain call. Do the request to the same domain:

```
$.post("http://www.r4ge.ro/php/register.php", {
```

or:

```
$.post("/php/register.php", {
```

Answer (score 0):

The script wasn't called in the html. sorry for wasting time. A simple
    `<script src="js/registerform.js"></script>` Fixed it.